# Securing a Windows WebAPI RESTful Interface Called from an Angular 2 Application Hosted in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint

I have an Angular 2 Application that is to be hosted in a SharePoint instance.  The target audience is users internal to the company which makes our SharePoint portal the ideal host as it requires users to authenticate.

The problem of course is that the RESTful API I've written (C#, Web API) needs to be secured and my preference would be to not force our users to authenticate a second time.  As Angular 2 is a client-side technology, the requests are coming from the browser which could be anywhere.

So my question, in one sentence, would be: how can I tell from my API that the request is coming from a user that has logged into our SharePoint portal?

FYI: Hosting the API in Azure is a possibility; we do maintain Azure AD.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed.  Any help pointing me to a way forward would be appreciated.

Comment: Credentials are stored in the HTTP headers -- I would start there and use Fiddler to investigate the payload from various clients.  A lot of times you will see the tokens, etc. that are helpful.